# Path Analyzer customization : Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Tags: path-analyzer, experience-optimization

I am working on multi-tenant website. Now analytics report of all the tenants are coming on the same dashboard.
I need a solution where User of tenant-A should not be able to view report related to tenant-B.

Is it possible?

**Sitecore version : 8.2 update 5**